# Comparison tool (but not monitoring tool !)

Tags: html, wordpress, comparison, jahia

My university has decided to switch from its CMS Jahia to Wordpress. It results of 40'000 new pages hosted on Wordpress. My work is to find/modify/create a tool to compare the old pages hosted on Jahia and the new ones on Wordpress, in order to find what is missing out.

I did many researchs but only found "monitoring tools", which is not what I'm looking for !

Do you have any recommandation ? Thanks !

(and sorry for my pretty bad english)

Comment: what exactly do you want form the tool? to check the design + functionality to be the same or what exactly to compare?

Comment: Essentialy the design (the layout, sequences, differences)

Comment: try to look into web crawlers and in this area, more I cannot help you

Comment: Too bad, I heard somewhere about "fuzzy search matching", which seems to fit perfectly for my request.